# Magento : Custom attributes added in the api2.xml (custom module) are not visible in admin

Tags: api, rest, magento, attributes

I'm currently trying to extend the Magento Rest API.
I need to add some features like :

- Retrieve the categories
- Add a category
- etc.

The problem is that I'm not able to allow a Rest Role to read the new attributes added with the new module.

In "Rest - Roles", there is no problem, I can allow my role to access the "retrieve" function, but when I go to the "Rest - Attributes", nothing appears so it's impossible to allow anything for my new module..

If I try to send the request I have an error :

- 403 : Forbidden {"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}}.

If somebody can help me.. Thanks !

*api2.xml*

```
<config>
<api2>
    <resource_groups>
        <categoriesmanagement translate="title" module="api2">
            <title>ExtendedRest API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </categoriesmanagement>
    </resource_groups>
    <resources>
        <categoriesmanagement translate="title" module="api2">
            <group>categoriesmanagement</group>
            <model>categoriesmanagement/api2_category</model>
            <title>Category Management</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </admin>
            </privileges>
            <attributes>
                <entity_id>Category ID</entity_id>
                <name>Name</name>
                <parent_id>Category Parent ID</parent_id>
                <is_active>Active</is_active>
                <level>Level</level>
                <position>Position</position>
                <children>Children Ids</children>
                <url_key>URL key</url_key>
                <store_id>Store ID</store_id>
            </attributes>
            <routes>
                <route_collection>
                    <route>/extendedrest/categoriesmanagement</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route_collection>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </categoriesmanagement>
    </resources>
</api2></config>
```

Comment: Please show your `api2.xml` file too.

Comment: I don't know why.. Maybe because Magento can't find attributes in the database ? How can we link our attributes with existing attributes of the product category entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is a lack of `working_model`, which must be a child of your resource type.  e.g.

```
<resources>
    <categoriesmanagement translate="title" module="api2">
        <group>categoriesmanagement</group>
        <model>categoriesmanagement/api2_category</model>
        <working_model>catalog/category</working_model>
```

The `working_model` value is used in `Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::getEavAttributes` to reference your declaration with database entities, or as you put it, "link our attributes with existing attributes".

---

I have done this successfully in my own project, [Extra RESTful](https://github.com/clockworkgeek/Magento-Extra-RESTful).  It already does what you are attempting but my time is too tight to work on it now.  It is open source in the hope that others can work on it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will help me a lot. I haven't modman so I'll install it manually. I haven't found my problem.. Can you explain me what is the utility of "include attribute" and "exclude attribute" please ?

Comment: Think of product attributes, you can add them in admin and they will show in the API without having to write any XML.  The `<attributes>` node is for adding those which aren't so clearly defined in EAV and `<exclude_attributes>` is for removing those which are defined in EAV but you want to limit them.  `<exclude_attributes>` can be useful for making read-only attributes.